# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'version' of null angular 4

Tags: angular, nouislider

I am using ng2-nouislider in an angular 4 application with below dependency. I am successfully able to build with and without --aot and got no error however on browser I am getting error "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'version' of null" in an infinite loop so can anyone suggest what could be reason for this problem as I went through different solution on github but nothing seems to be working for me.

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.2.6",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "6.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "0.0.3",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.3.0",
    "angular2-cookie": "^1.2.6",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "enhanced-resolve": "^3.3.0",
    "file-saver": "^1.3.3",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "ng-click-outside": "^2.3.4",
    "ng2-lazy-trumbowyg": "^2.3.1",
    "ng2-nouislider": "1.6.2",
    "ng2-select2": "^1.0.0-beta.10",
    "ngx-cookie": "^1.0.0",
    "ngx-smart-modal": "^2.0.3",
    "nouislider": "^10.1.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "select2": "^4.0.3",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  }
```

Error:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but probably in CoverLetterEditorComponent you are using this variable and it is not initialized yet. Show us code of that component.

Comment: I am not using any undeclared variable and even If i did error should be printed on console only once whether in this case it is recurring error.